# Coredata, NSOrderedSet and iCloud

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, nsorderedset

I have been searching around for information about use of NSOrderedSet with iCloud as my app uses this extensively.

I want to use iCloud as the backup mechanism for my core data app but am getting 'hints' looking around that this mechanism cannot be used with iCloud, but cannot find anything concrete to verify this.

Is this true, even with iOS7?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still stated in the iCloud Core Data Programming Guide that it's not supported:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's very tedious!  And I bet as soon as I've modified to use and 'order' field, iOS8.0 will be released which supports it!

Comment: Yep. There must be some good reason it's not supported, probably it's tough to keep in sync. Use floats to order and have a look in Big Nerd Ranch's iOS book for a method to add new things between two old ones.

Comment: You can add something like 1.5 between 1 and 2, then 1.25 between those. Don't have to re-index the whole list.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it is still not supported in iCloud. It wouldn't surprise me if they don't do it at all. It's been 3 years now.

I recently added ordered relationships to [Ensembles](http://ensembles.io), which is a sync framework for Core Data, and can also work with iCloud. To get it to work, we had to store all the indexes and object identities, every time the relationship was modified. It works, but it does result in more data than you would like. That's perhaps why Apple hasn't done it.

You can order relationships yourself, using integer or float parameters. Be careful with floats that you don't hit the machine precision. (e.g. Dividing by 2 each time can reach this limit with relatively few insertions)